# Why does my heartbeat process die as soon as it starts?

Tags: node.js, events

I have a simple heartbeat process that should run forever and continue beating, but it dies as soon I start it.

```
$ node heartbeat.js
Starting heartbeats
$
```

My heartbeat script is quite straightforward.

```
var heartbeats = require('heartbeats');

// tell me that the script is starting
console.log('Starting heartbeats');

// create a heart that beats every second
var heart = heartbeats.createHeart(1000);

// every heartbeat, tell me the beat number
heart.createEvent(1, function(heartbeat, last){
  console.log('beat number ' + heart.age);
});
```

However adding `process.stdin.resume();` at the end keeps it running forever:

```
$ node heartbeat.js
Starting heartbeats
beat number 1
beat number 2
beat number 3
...
```

Why does it do this?

Comment: Please note my updated answer. I've pushed a fix that should behave as expected now without any additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

In response to your question, I've just published [Heartbeats ^4.0.1](https://github.com/arjunmehta/heartbeats/releases/tag/v4.0.1). It will now keep your app alive if there are any events created, and will continue to keep it alive until the very last event completes.

Thank you for pointing this out!

---

**Original Answer**

I'm the author of the module, and @SergeyLapin is correct. Heartbeats is not currently meant to keep your app alive. I figured, this would be the expected behavior for most people.

However you can keep your app alive by adding at the end of your code:

```
heart.interval.ref();
```

I will modify the API and add a new feature to ensure that if there are events, that the app is kept alive at least as long as there are events.

Answer (score 2):

`heartbeats` calls `.unref` for timers it sets ([github](https://github.com/arjunmehta/heartbeats/blob/master/lib/heart.js#L29)), which means it does not require event loop to remain active.
As there are no other listeners in your example, it quits.

`process.stdin.resume();` makes node to wait for user's input, so the process remains alive.

Looks like `heartbeats` is not meant to keep the app alive only by itself, but rather to run in the background.

Comment: Abu recommendations on how to keep the app running forever?

Comment: This is a correct answer. Heartbeats will not keep your app active.